# How do I add a key listener to a LWJGL display?

Tags: java, lwjgl, keylistener

I am trying to add a key listener to my display from LWJGL. I can see where I am getting the error in my code, and I think that the problem is caused because I am trying trying to add my key listener, "input", to a class. In all the examples I have seen the key listener is added to a JFrame, but I am not using one so I don't know what to add it to. I'm providing the class that I am having the error in and the key listener I created. Please ignore some of the comments because the majority of them are just failed pieces of code. The error I'm getting is on line 39 of Initializer. The line is "this.addKeyListener(input);". Another thing I wanted to add, currently the code between the long lines of "/"s are useless so it would be better to ignore them. Thank you for the help.

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;

import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class Initializer {
    static int height = 800;
    static int width = 600;
    public static Camera cam;
    private InputHandler input;

public void start() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(height,width));
        Display.setTitle("3D OpenGL");
        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // init OpenGL here
    cam = new Camera(70, (float)Display.getWidth()/(float)Display.getHeight(), 0.3f, 1000);
    float x = 0;

    //Makes cursor disappear
    Mouse.setGrabbed(true);
    //displayExample.getContentPane().setCursor(c);

    input = new InputHandler();
    this.addKeyListener(input);

    Keyboard.enableRepeatEvents(false);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested() && !Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        Movement2Vector movement = new Movement2Vector(0, 0);



        //Current issue is that the 2 statements below are not working to check for which key is pressed and if a key is pressed



        int key = Keyboard.getEventKey();
        boolean pressed = Keyboard.getEventKeyState();
        System.out.println(pressed);
        Movement2Vector vec = Direction.of(key);
        //System.out.println(vec.getX() + ", " + vec.getY());
        if (pressed) {
          movement = movement.add2Vector(vec);
          cam.moveCam(movement);
        } else if (movement != new Movement2Vector(0, 0) && movement == vec) {
          movement = new Movement2Vector(0, 0);
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Checks for movement
        //Movement mov = new Movement();
        //Initialized Delta
        Delta.lastFrame = Delta.getTime();

        // render OpenGL here
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glLoadIdentity();
        cam.useView();

        glPushMatrix();
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0f);
        glTranslatef(0,0,-10);
        glRotatef(x, 2.5f, 1.5f , 0);
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        CreateCube cube = new CreateCube(-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1);
        /*glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            //FrontFace
            glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
            glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
            glVertex3f(1,1,1);
            glVertex3f(1,-1,1);

            //BackFace
            glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
            glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
            glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
            glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);

            //BottomFace
            glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
            glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
            glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
            glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);

            //TopFace
            glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
            glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
            glVertex3f(1,1,1);
            glVertex3f(1,1,-1);

            //LeftFace
            glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
            glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
            glVertex3f(1,-1,1);
            glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);

            //Right Face
            glVertex3f(-1,1,-1);
            glVertex3f(1,1,-1);
            glVertex3f(1,1,1);
            glVertex3f(-1,1,1);
        glEnd();*/
        glPopMatrix();
        for(int i=-15; i<4; i++){
            for(int y=-1; y<2; y++){
                Random r = new Random();
                glColor3f(0.3f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
                CreateCube cubeTest = new CreateCube(y-1, -4, i-1, y+1, -2, i+1);
            }
        }


        x += 1f;
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Initializer displayExample = new Initializer();
    displayExample.start();
}
}
```

Key Listener class

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;


public class InputHandler implements KeyListener, FocusListener{

    public boolean[] key = new boolean[68836];

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)){
            Initializer.cam.moveForward(0.005f*Delta.getDelta());
        }
        else if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)){
            Initializer.cam.moveForward(-0.005f*Delta.getDelta());
        }
        else if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)){
            Initializer.cam.moveSideways(0.005f*Delta.getDelta());
        }
        else if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)){
            Initializer.cam.moveSideways(-0.005f*Delta.getDelta());
        }
        else if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)){
            Initializer.cam.moveUp(0.005f*Delta.getDelta());
        }
        else if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LSHIFT)){
            Initializer.cam.moveUp(-0.005f*Delta.getDelta());
        }

        /*int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode > 0 && keyCode < key.length){
            key[keyCode] = true;
        }*/

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {       
        /*for(int i = 0; i < key.length; i++){
            key[i] = false;
        }*/

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lwjgl then you can import`import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;`
and you can use this instead which I find much more efficient

```
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)){
```